# integrate newrelic in flink scala project

Tags: scala, apache-flink, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I want to integrate newrelic in my flink project. I have downloaded my newrelic.yml file from my account and have changed the app name only and I have created a folder named newrelic in my project root folder and have placed newrelic.yml file in it.

I have also placed the following dependency in my buld.sbt file:

```
"com.newrelic.agent.java" % "newrelic-api" % "3.0.0"
```

I am using the following command to run my jar:

```
flink run -m yarn-cluster -yn 2 -c Main /home/hadoop/test-assembly-0.2.jar
```

I guess, my code is not able to read my newrelic.yml file because I can't see my app name in newrelic. Do i need to initialize newrelic agent somewhere (if yes, how?). Please help me with this integration.

Comment: I don't know what newrelic is or does, but I think the problem is that the file is not accessible from your cluster. Please remember the flink run command is just a client and it submits the jar to the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You should only need the newrelic.jar and newrelic.yml files to be accessible and have `-javaagent:path/to/newrelic.jar` passed to the JVM as an argument. You could try putting both **newrelic.jar** and **newrelic.yml** into your **lib/** directory so they get copied to the job & task managers, then adding this to your **conf/flink-conf.yaml**:

`env.java.opts: -javaagent:lib/newrelic.jar`

Both New Relic files should be in the same directory and you ought to be able to remove the New Relic line from your **build.sbt** file. Also double check that your license key is in the newrelic.yml file.

I haven't tested this but the main goal is for the .yml and .jar to be accessible in the same directory(the yml can go into a different directory but other JVM arguments will need to be passed to reference it) and to pass `-javaagent:path/to/newrelic.jar` to as a JVM argument. If you run into issues try checking for new relic logs in the **log** folder of the directory where the .jar is located.